# Xtext problem referencing grammar A from validator of grammar B

Tags: xtext

In Xtext, how do I follow a reference from grammar B to grammar A, within a validator of grammar B (which is in the ui-plugin)? Consider the following example.

Grammar A is `org.xtext.people.People`

```
grammar org.xtext.people.People with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate people "http://www.xtext.org/people/People"

People:
    people+=Person*;

Person:
    'person' name=ID ';';
```

and an instance

```
person Alice {citizenship "MN"; id "12345"; }
person Bob {citizenship "CH"; id "54321";}
person Malice {citizenship "XXX"; id "66666"; }
```

At an airport, entries of people are recorded.

```
enter Alice;
enter Bob;
enter Malice;
```

Entries are modelled with a second grammar B `org.xtext.entries.Entries`

```
grammar org.xtext.entries.Entries with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate entries "http://www.xtext.org/entries/Entries"
import "http://www.xtext.org/people/People"

Entries:
    entries+=Entry*;

Entry:
    'enter' person=[Person] ';';
```

After ensuring that the Eclipse project `org.xtext.entries` has the project `org.xtext.people` on it's classpath, and ensuring that the `org.xtext.entries` plugin has the `org.xtext.people` as a dependency, all works as expected.

There is a travel ban on people from country XXX, although certain deserving people are excluded. Only the CIA knows who is excluded from the ban. Entries must not be allowed for people from XXX unless excluded.

The updated grammar is

```
grammar org.xtext.entries.Entries with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate entries "http://www.xtext.org/entries/Entries"


import "http://www.xtext.org/people/People"

Entries:
    entries+=Entry*;

Entry:
    travelBanOverride=TravelBanOverride?
    'enter' person=[Person] ';';

TravelBanOverride: '@TravelBanOverride' '(' code=STRING ')';
```

with validator

```
package org.xtext.entries.validation

import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Check
import org.xtext.entries.entries.EntriesPackage
import org.xtext.entries.entries.Entry
import org.xtext.entries.CIA

class EntriesValidator extends AbstractEntriesValidator {

    public static val BAN = 'BAN'
    public static val ILLEGAL_OVERRIDE = 'ILLEGAL_OVERRIDE'

    @Check
    def checkBan(Entry entry) {
        if (entry.person.citizenship == "XXX") {
            if (entry.travelBanOverride === null) {
                error('Violation of Travel Ban', EntriesPackage.Literals.ENTRY__PERSON, BAN)
            } 
            else {
                val overridecode = entry.travelBanOverride.code;
                val valid = CIA.valid(entry.person.name, entry.person.id, overridecode)
                if (!valid) {
                    error('Illegal override code', EntriesPackage.Literals.ENTRY__TRAVEL_BAN_OVERRIDE, ILLEGAL_OVERRIDE)
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

where the driver for the external CIA web-app is modelled for example by

```
package org.xtext.entries;

public class CIA {


    public static boolean valid(String name, String id, String overrideCode) {
        System.out.println("UNValid["+name+","+overrideCode+"]");
        return name.equals("Malice") && id.equals("66666") && overrideCode.equals("123");
    }

}
```

The validations work as expected.

I now wish to provided a quick-fix for `BAN`, that checks for an override code from the CIA.

```
package org.xtext.entries.ui.quickfix

import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.DefaultQuickfixProvider
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.Fix
import org.xtext.entries.validation.EntriesValidator
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Issue
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.IssueResolutionAcceptor
import org.xtext.entries.entries.Entry
import org.xtext.entries.Helper

class EntriesQuickfixProvider extends DefaultQuickfixProvider {

    @Fix(EntriesValidator.BAN)
    def tryOverride(Issue issue, IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
        acceptor.accept(issue, 'Try override', 'Override if CIA says so.', 'override.png') 
        [element ,context |
            val entry = element as Entry
            // val person = entry.person // no such attribute
             //val person = Helper.get(entry); // The method get(Entry) from the type Helper refers to the missing type Object
        ]
    }
}
```

The first commented line does not compile: there is no attribute `person`. The second commented line is an attempt to solve the problem by getting a helper class in `org.xtext.entries` to get the person, but this does not compile either, giving a *"The method get(Entry) from the type Helper refers to the missing type Object"* error message.

For completeness, here is that helper.

```
package org.xtext.entries

import org.xtext.people.people.Person
import org.xtext.entries.entries.Entry

class Helper {

    static def Person get(Entry entry) {
        return entry.person;
    }

}
```

Further, `entry.travelBanOverride` compiles fine, but `entry.person` does not. Clicking on Entry in Eclipse takes one to the expected code, which has both `travelBanOverride` and `person`.

The issue does not occur with a Java class in the same project and package.

```
package org.xtext.entries.ui.quickfix;

import org.xtext.entries.entries.Entry;
import org.xtext.people.people.Person;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Entry entry = null;
        Person p = entry.getPerson();
    }
}
```

Rewriting the quickfix in Java solves the problem.

```
package org.xtext.entries.ui.quickfix;

import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.DefaultQuickfixProvider;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.Fix;
import org.xtext.entries.validation.EntriesValidator;
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Issue;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.IssueResolutionAcceptor;
import org.xtext.entries.entries.Entry;
import org.xtext.entries.Helper;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.edit.IModificationContext;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.edit.ISemanticModification;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.xtext.entries.entries.Entry;
import org.xtext.people.people.Person;

public class EntriesQuickfixProvider extends DefaultQuickfixProvider {



@Fix(EntriesValidator.BAN)
    public void tryOverride(final Issue issue, IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
        acceptor.accept(issue,
            "Try to override", 
            "Override",
            "override.gif", 
            new ISemanticModification() {
                public void apply(EObject element, IModificationContext context) {
                    Entry entry = (Entry) element;
                    System.out.println(entry.getPerson());
                }
            }
        );
}

}
```

- How do I follow a reference from grammar B (Entries) to grammar A (People), within a validator of grammar B?

Comment: i really cannot follow your issue: if you import the right Entry class then there should be a entry.person. for me it looks like there is a error in how you reference the dsls from each other. are you sure you added references to the manifest in the correct way (added it to required bundles)? you talk about project on the classpath. maybe you did the wrong thing

Comment: "val entry = element as Entry" complies fine. If I click on Entry it takes me to the definition with the expected expected method getPerson. But the compiler will have none of it. Just to double check, following a reference from the ui project should be no different to following it from the primary project. There is no well-known/obvious reason for it not to be so?

Comment: `entry.travelBanOverride` compiles fine, but `entry.person` does not. Clicking on Entry in Eclipse takes one to the expected code, which has both `travelBanOverride` and `person`. I have updated the OP to reflect this.

Comment: It appears that the Java compiler has no problem. I have updated the OP with an example. Will try to write the quickfix in Java and see if this helps.

Comment: Rewriting the quickfix in Java solves the problem. I have updated the OP.

Comment: switching back to xtend, and it is working again. Seems to be a refreshing issue?

Comment: From that Description i have no idea. This having a reproducinle example would help

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is the following.

> After ensuring that the Eclipse project org.xtext.entries has the
>   project org.xtext.people on it's classpath, and ensuring that the
>   org.xtext.entries plugin has the org.xtext.people as a dependency, all
>   works as expected.

The `org.xtext.entries.ui` ui-plugin must *also* have the `org.xtext.people` on its Java (Eclipse project) build path. Exporting and making a plugin-dependency it not enough.

Note that this setting should be made early, before crafting the quick-fix, because the Xtend editor has refreshing issues.